# Brownian Motion and hitting times

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I am having trouble with a step in the proof of Theorem 2.9.6 of Karatzas and Shreve's *Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus*. I need to prove that, given a Brownian motion $W$,
$$\beta_t:=\inf\{s>t; W_s=0\}$$

is an optional time for every $t\ge 0$.

Here is my attempt: fix $t\ge0$, and let $T \in \mathbb{R}$.  If $T \le t$, $\{\beta_t <T\}=\emptyset\in\mathcal{F}_T$. Otherwise,
$$\{\beta_t<T\}=\bigcup_{s<t'<t}\{W_{t'}=0\}\in \sigma\left( \bigcup_{s<t'<t}\mathcal{F}_{t'}\right)\subseteq \mathcal{F}_t.$$

Is this correct? If not, there is some hint I could follow? Thank you!

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Note that an uncountable union of measurable sets need not be measurable. You will need to use that a continuous function $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ has a root in $[a,b]$ iff $$\left\{ x \in [a,b]; |f(x)| \leq \frac{1}{k} \right\} \neq \emptyset$$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I solved the problem. Given $T>t$, we have that

$$\{\beta_t \ge T\}=\bigcap_n A_n,$$

where $A_n=\{W_s\neq 0; s\in[t+1/n,T-1/n]\}$. But since $W$ is continuous and $[t+1/n,T-1/n]$ is closed, we have
$$A_n = \bigcup_{k\ge 1} \bigcap_{q\in[t+1/n,T-1/n]\cap\mathbb{Q}}\{|W_q|\ge1/k\} \in \mathcal{F}_T.$$

Therefore $\{\beta_t<T\}=\{\beta_t \ge T\}^c\in \mathcal{F}_T$.